# Mapbox change marker location and color

Tags: javascript, leaflet

The following code shows a marker and a popup that shows the lat and long whenever I click on the map.

I want the marker to change color from blue to red, and I want the popup to be above the marker so that it doesn't cover the marker. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([40.7127837, -74.0059413]).addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(mymap)
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a mapbox-gl question, this is a Leaflet question

Answer (score 0):

The marker uses an icon image to display, so you will need to create your own custom icon, with the iconUrl pointing at the image you want to use for the marker, and then tell the marker to use your custom icon when rendering. You can also specify the popupAnchor in the icon settings to move the popup away from the icon

Example ([Leaflet docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon))

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'my-icon.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95],
  iconAnchor: [22, 94],
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
  shadowSize: [68, 95],
  shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});

L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks,  this changed the color of my marker, but it makes the marker point to the wrong coordinates. I want the marker to be on the right coordinates with the popup above that marker. I think I need to do something with the following code to change the popup coordinates, but not sure how to do that.       popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);

Comment: You need to pass the marker the correct co-ordinates. So L.marker([50.505, 30.57], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map); in the example  would become L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(mymap) as you have in your original code.